What to do when put on a Performance Improvement Plan (PIP)?
I was put on a Performance Improvement Plan (PIP), I have been in this company since 10 months, and had joined as a New Grad, It's a tech company.
When you are put on PIP, what are the expectations? Manager told me my progress will be tracked and if I don't show improvement by end of it, then... and nothing was told, though vague the outcome is clear.
I want to know is the progress actually tracked, if so how can someone show improvement which is noticeable, and if it's worth putting effort at all. What should be the best thing to do at the moment?

Have you read all the other questions here on PIPs?

https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/104589/pip-and-need-improvement-rating

If they have not told you what they expect, then the PIP is a formality before a layoff and you should look for another job. You cannot meet expectations you don't know, and that is probably on purpose. Basically what most existing answers here say.

https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/177539/surviving-a-pip-with-no-earlier-warnings

I want to know is the progress actually tracked - The manager told you it is tracked, so why would you ask if it is actually tracked? Ask your manager for identifiable and quantifiable expectations.

A PIP can be survived. It takes negotiating very specific achievable goals for the PIP period, getting agreement that those are your ONLY tasks until they are met, and then achieving them. It also requires that your first line manager be more honest than whoever demanded they put you on a PIP.

https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/73958/are-there-any-specific-strategies-for-surviving-a-pip

https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/171656/how-to-deal-with-potential-pip

https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/187650/how-often-does-a-performance-improvement-plan-pip-work-out-well

And possibly others. Yes, your job is on the line if you fail to meet the PIP goals, so unless you can demonstrate your value to the company you should also be getting ready to job hunt.

This question is similar to: Surviving a PIP with no earlier warnings. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

It is time for self reflection and evaluation.  This is a pivotal part of your career but no where near the end.  Your character and confidence will be put to a test, but you can overcome.  Its a bit troubling that you were put on a PIP for a first job in less than a year.
The most important part of the PIP is why you were placed on such.  You need to understand this.  If this requires subsequent meetings with your manager or your manager and others to clarify then do that.  Gaining clarity on how to move forward is the most important part of this.
Its odd that you say that progress will be tracked but are unsure of what will be tracked.  You either did not understand why you were placed on a PIP or it was not communicated.  You should be telling us why you were placed on such.
Of course you will be let go if you do not make progress.
The bit you relayed I would say that your manager seems like a nice person.  He could not bring himself to say you would be fired.
If the reason you were put on a PIP was due to communication, then you need to get better at that.  Overly communicate with your team lead and manager.  Walk over and talk to them if possible, and if not email/message them about your status and plans.
If the reason you were put on a PIP was general irresponsibility, then you just need to correct that.  Show up early, go home late.  Work while you are at work.  Help others.  Be respectful and kind to everyone.  If you were are expected to work 8 hours per day, work 9.  Take care of your corporate training and ancillary requirements before their due date.
It may be a technical issue.  That is you do not have the expertise to do the job.  Work with your manager on how to increase this skill or have you reassigned.  This may take extensive after hours studying.
So what is the reason you were place on a PIP?

Most of the comments are actually great answers. Read the links.
It comes down to several key points and you ability to be act on them:

Do you see yourself as a long-term fit in the company?
Do you see yourself being valuable to the company?
Can you take the information and direction in the PIP and run with it?

Long-term fit means technical, cultural, etc. Is this where you want to be.
